# MySQL server has gone away (host vs ip)

Tags: mysql, http, golang

Тема мусолилась много еще с древних времен, когда на мамонтов ходили с копьями

Есть скриптец на php который проверяет коннект к серверам, дергается кроном каждые 5-ть минут
При ошибке шлет ее на почту и еще смс-кой будит

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time',10);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

function logger($obj){echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')," ::: ",print_r($obj,TRUE),"\n";}
function shutdown(){ if( $a = error_get_last() ) logger($a); else logger(".:: N O  E R R O R S ::."); }
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

function errorConnection($host,$user,$pass,$base)
{
    $error = FALSE;
    $db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$base);
    if( $db->connect_errno ) return "[1] ".$db->connect_error;
    if( !$db->query("SET @tstcon=1") ) $error = "[2] ".$db->error;
    $db->close();
    return $error;
}

$mysqlUser = 'tstcon';
$mysqlPass = 'tstcon';
$mysqlBase = 'tstcon';

$arrHost = [
    ['host'=>'1.site.ru','ip'=>'11.11.11.11'],
    ['host'=>'2.site.ru','ip'=>'22.22.22.22'],
    ['host'=>'3.site.ru','ip'=>'33.33.33.33'],
    ['host'=>'4.site.ru','ip'=>'44.44.44.44'],
];

logger(".:: S T A R T  T E S T ::.");

$resMsg = '';
$errorExist = FALSE;
$errorHostSMS = '';
foreach( $arrHost AS $h )
{
    $ip = $h['ip'];
    $host = $h['host'];
    if( $error = errorConnection($host,$mysqlUser,$mysqlPass,$mysqlBase) )
    {
        $errorExist = TRUE;

        $_msg = "$host $error [byHOST]";
        $resMsg .= "$_msg<br>";
        logger("$host $error");
        $errorHostSMS .= "\n{$_msg}";

        if( $error = errorConnection($ip,$mysqlUser,$mysqlPass,$mysqlBase) )
        {
            $_msg = "$host $error [byIP]";
            $resMsg .= "$_msg<br>";
            logger("$host $error");
            $errorHostSMS .= "\n{$_msg}";
        }
        else
        {
            $_msg = "$host GOOD [byIP]";
            $resMsg .= "$_msg<br>";
            logger("$host $error");
            $errorHostSMS .= "\n{$_msg}";

            /// Добавим процесс-лист /// Пока костыльно
            $db = new mysqli($ip,$mysqlUser,$mysqlPass,$mysqlBase);
            $sql = "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;";
            $res = $db->query($sql);
            if( @$res->num_rows )
            {
                $resMsg .= "PROCESS LIST >>><br>";
                while( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() )
                {
                    $resMsg .= implode(' ::: ',$row)."<br>";
                }
                $resMsg .= "PROCESS LIST <<<<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_msg = "$host доступен";
        $resMsg .= "$_msg<br>";
        logger("$host доступен");
        ///$errorHostSMS .= "\n{$_msg}";
    }
}
if( $errorExist )
{
    /// ОТправляет на почту и смс
}
```

Сперва не обращал внимание на ночные сообщения, но они стали надоедать
Вдруг гугл в этот момент зайдет, или еще того, клиент!

Сообщение примерно такое:

```
1.site.ru доступен
2.site.ru доступен
3.site.ru [1] MySQL server has gone away [byHOST]
3.site.ru GOOD [byIP]
PROCESS LIST >>>
23235528 ::: tstcon ::: 33.33.33.33:54562 ::: tstcon ::: Query ::: 0 ::: ::: SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
PROCESS LIST <<<
4.site.ru доступен
```

Я почитал сперва про "MySQL server has gone away", и возможно не правильно понял, то это сервер сам разрывает соединения из-за долгого запроса или слишком большого пакета?!

Мои размышления:
1. Скрипт дергается каждые 5-ть минут, сообщение одно, значит разово, в процесс листе чисто
2. После коннекта по хосту, я сразу дергаю тот же код только коннект уже по IP, доли секунды и все норм; Есть отдельный скрипт, что вне этого запросы только мониторит все sql запросы в течение суток, там тоже пусто в это время
3. Остается предположить, что проблема сетевая; Такое может быть?

Ночью на сервере отрабатывает скрипт бекапа: дампятся базы, на лету сжимаются, потом чистятся по времени старые, и в конце заливка в хранилище
Сперва подумал, что дело в дампах и серверу не до тестового коннекта, но судя по времени, чую дело в другом

Сообщение пришло на почту в 4:21 по мск
В логах, тоже по мск:

```
... не беру во внимание, что было раньше ...
2019/04/26 04:13:09 - Synchronization
rclone sync /opt/backups StorageName:3.site.ru
2019/04/26 04:14:11 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
2019/04/26 04:14:11 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
2019/04/26 04:14:11 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
2019/04/26 04:14:11 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
2019/04/26 04:14:11 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
2019/04/26 04:14:11 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
2019/04/26 04:22:06 - ... End of script ...
```

На эти вот ошибки хостер, у которого арендуем облачное хранилище, сказал не обращать внимание, сославшись на баг самого Go, на котором написан rclone

Я не сетевик, но вот как есть, что rclone забивает dns запросы и по этому по хосту не могу подрубиться
Может быть такое?

Все вот такие "MySQL server has gone away" ночью приходятся на момент синхронизации с внешним хранилищем
Я все это написал, что бы была полная картина => подытожим

В логах (tail /var/log/mysql/error.log) пусто, я туда первым делом, даже конфиг перепроверил, лог именно туда пишется

Первое, что отдал гугл при поиске по ошибке:
[https://ruhighload.com/mysql+server+has+gone+away+-+как+пофиксить](https://ruhighload.com/mysql+server+has+gone+away+-+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)

1. Таймаут соединения
2. Большой или некорректный пакет

Предполагаю, что все таки первое, ну какой тут от меня пакет
Но все равно как то мутно и размазано, иду на офсайт:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gone-away.html

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is that the server timed out and closed the connection.

То есть сервер сам закрыл соединение?

> Учитываю мои слабые знания сети, есть что-то такое странное как
>   SYN-AСK
>   +   Ошибка "MySQL server has gone away" возникает во время коннекта, а не запроса

Тогда имеет место быть, что сервер1 послал запрос на подключение к серверу2

сервер2 сказал, что готов, и в ответ: я жду, ожидая от сервера1 каких то данных

Но ввиду возможно работы rclone, тех ошибок, произошло, не знаю как правильно сказать, замусоривание канала в частности DNS, раз по IP норм, и сервер2 не дождался подтверждения на коннект от сервера1

Верное предположение?
Как это можно исправить?